# Why does the type System.__ComObject claim (sometimes) to be public when it is not?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, encapsulation, cil

Just an oddity I happened to discover when I was reflecting over all types to check something else out of curiosity.

Why does the class `System.__ComObject` of the assembly `mscorlib.dll` (sometimes?) claim to be public when in fact it seems to be non-public? If I run the following code in a simple C# console application:

```
var t = Type.GetType("System.__ComObject");
Console.WriteLine(t.IsPublic);   // "True"   ?!
Console.WriteLine(t.IsVisible);  // "False"
```

the output seems conflicting. A non-nested type (`t.IsNested` is false) should give the same truth value for `IsPublic` and `IsVisible`. When I look at the assembly with `IL DASM` I see:

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit System.__ComObject
       extends System.MarshalByRefObject
{
} // end of class System.__ComObject
```

which, to me, looks very much like a *non-public* class, something which would correspond to the C# code below:

```
namespace System
{
    // not public
    internal class __ComObject : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I compare to another type which has a similar name, `System.__Canon`, and similar IL modifiers, both `IsPublic` and `IsVisible` return false as expected.

Does anyone know why (and when) `Type.GetType("System.__ComObject").IsPublic` gives true?

Comment: System.__ComObject and System.__Canon are very different - first is COM object(IsCOMObject==true) - that is why I think it is Public and the second not.

Comment: @Mihail If I use `var t = typeof(Uri).Assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MSAdminBase");` I have another type `t` which also `IsCOMObject`, but `IsNotPublic`. So that seems to be a "counterexample" to that explanation, unless this is something that depends on the assembly (`System.Net.Mail.MSAdminBase` is in another assembly, compared to `System.__ComObject`).

Comment: All I can figure out is, this might be a defect! I came across some similar stuff, may be you guys came across the same too. Follow [link](http://microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.interop.narkive.com/06Y4MWuX/reflection-messing-up-the-type-hierarchy)

Comment: @Nilesh It looks like that link describes the very same problem (or a problem which includes both my question and something more). Unfortunately there is no explanation there. It seems that this situation is unchanged for six years. If it were a bug, that would be strange. But a very interesting comment!

Comment: Congratulations to Noseratio whose answer automatically gave him some reputation after the bounty had expired. However, I still feel my answer is unanswered. Technically `IsPublic` works by calling the abstract `GetAttributeFlagsImpl`, but that doesn't help me understand what's special about `__ComObject`. Whether this behavior is necessary and by design, or it is a bug, I don't know, and it would be interesting to know why `__ComObject` is different than other types here.

Answer (score 10):

[Mono's implementation](https://github.com/mosa/Mono-Class-Libraries/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/__ComObject.Original.cs) of `__ComObject` may give some clues. It is indeed declared as *internal*, but the comments say *"It has no public methods, its functionality is exposed trough `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal`"*. I haven't dug into `Marshal`, but I would assume it is responsible for the implementation of `GetType()`, so it could customize `IsPublic` property too.

In my experience, `Type.GetType("System.__ComObject").IsPublic` is always `true`. Regarding `GetType("System.Net.Mail.MSAdminBase")`, I believe it is a COM class exposed via a [customized primary interop assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7112ksf7.asp), where the visibility of a type can be explicitly controlled (although it's just my thinking, no research has been done).

**[UPDATE]**

I've got the [latest Framework source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) and found I was wrong about my assumption that customization of `IsPublic` property for `__ComObject` Type is done by `Marshal`. Actually, it is done by unmanaged code. `Object.GetType()` is defined inside Object.cs like this:

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public extern Type GetType();
```

The unmanaged source code for its implementation in .NET 4.x is not available, but it is [available](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917) for .NET 2.0. There's an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105575/how-is-reflection-implemented-in-c) about `Object.GetType` implementation in .NET 2.0. I'd just add, `IsPublic` is defined by `System.Runtime.InteropServices._Type` interface which `System.Type` derives from, and can be overridden by any of `System.Type`-descendent classes. Apparently, an implementation of such class is returned by `Object.GetType`, and that's happening inside `ObjectNative::GetClass` (sscli20\clr\src\vm\comobject.cpp), as shown in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105575/how-is-reflection-implemented-in-c):

```
if (!objRef->IsThunking())
    refType = typeHandle.GetManagedClassObject();
else
    refType = CRemotingServices::GetClass(objRef);
```

I confirm that the behavior of `IsPublic` depends on the Framework version. I tried the following PowerShell script in different VMs:

```
Write-Host ([System.Environment]::Version) ([Type]::GetType("System.__ComObject")).IsPublic
```

The output is:

```
2.0.50727.3643 False (WinXP)
4.0.30319.18052 True (Win7)
4.0.30319.19079 True (Win8)
```

Apparently, it has changed from `False` to `True` since .NET 2.0. I agree that `True` is inconsistent with the declaration of `__ComObject` (`internal class __ComObject ...`). I personally see no reason for such change, because the only way to get an instance of `__ComObject` is through interop.

Comment: I haven't tested this in Mono. I didn't find anything in the source code you linked that seemed relevant, to me. I'm not sure what you mean to say about `GetType` and `IsPublic`. The latter is a non-virtual (though interface implementing) instance property on the abstract `System.Type` class, so I need explanation on how `__ComObject` or `Marshal` "could customize" it (your words). The reason why I say "(sometimes)" in the question, is that I tested this in PowerShell on two different machine, with one machine treating (through PowerShell) `__ComObject` as non-public, apparently.

Comment: I've tried the following with PowerShell: `Write-Host ([System.Environment]::Version) ([Type]::GetType("System.__ComObject")).IsPublic`, the output: `4.0.30319.19079 True`(Win8), `4.0.30319.18052 True` (Win7), `2.0.50727.3643 False` (WinXP). Apparently, the result of `IsPublic` for `__ComObject` depends on the framework version. I'll do some research and provide the explanation on `Marshal` you requested.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by saying that (`IsPublic`) _is a non-virtual (though interface implementing) instance property_ on the abstract `System.Type`. The property is defined in `System.Runtime.InteropServices._Type` interface, so it's virtual by definition and can be overridden by any derived class, same as `IsCOMObject`. `System.Type` doesn't implement `IsPublic`, but some of its derived classes do, e.g. `System.RuntimeType`. I admit I was wrong assuming the customization is done by `Marshal` though, it's actually done with unmanaged code. I've updated my answer with more details.

Comment: Regarding PowerShell, I have seen similar behavior. On machines where `__ComObject` seems to be public, you can actually use it directly in PowerShell it seems. For example `[__ComObject]` will give the `Type` object for the class. And `[__ComObject]$x = $null` will declare a variable `$x` of this type, and then `$x = 'Hello'` will fail afterwards because a string will not fit in a `__ComObject` variable. So it really acts "publicly" there.

Comment: Regarding `IsPublic`, I was talking about [this member of `System.Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.ispublic.aspx). As you see on that page, in C# terminology this property is non-virtual. However, in Visual C++ the terminology might be different. Looking at the CIL of the associated `get` accessor, the `get_IsPublic` method, wee see that it is declared `virtual final` in that terminology. This is because it implements a member of the interface `_Type`. But virtual-final (or virtual-sealed) still means it can's be overridden in any ordinary way.

Comment: About the virtual property, you're right, property as concept is just a syntactic sugar for method, but whether it's virtual or not is a CLR thing, as [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621410/why-are-c-sharp-interface-methods-not-declared-abstract-or-virtual). `Type` class is not sealed and, regardless of the language syntax differences, I can derive from it and override `IsPublic` (say, with managed C++ or VB.NET). Then I can pass an instance of my class anywhere `Type` is expected, and my implementation of `IsPublic` will be called. I meant just that under customization.

Comment: Regarding Powershell `[__ComObject]$x = $null`, this is interesting. Apparently, it means Powershell transparently deals with types through reflection? I didn't know that. Anyway, what you've found about `Type.GetType("System.__ComObject").IsPublic` being `true` really looks like a CLR bug to me :) I'd agree with Nilesh on that.

Comment: No, if you derive from `Type` you ***can't*** override `IsPublic`. As I explained it is `sealed`. The behavior of `IsPublic` will be determined by the implementation of [`GetAttributeFlagsImpl` (link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getattributeflagsimpl.aspx) you specify. But this discussion does not seem to be central to the question I asked. Our class `__ComObject` does not derive from `Type`. Why does `__ComObject` behave strangely?

Comment: Sorry for going off-topic, I just can't agree that that `Type` is [sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx). It is [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx) but *not sealed*: `public abstract class Type : MemberInfo, _Type, IReflect {...}`. I can derive from it and override its virtual methods & properties, including `IsPublic`. Indeed, this doesn't help to find the answer. Unfortunately, unmanaged sources for .NET 4.x `Object.GetType` are not available to dig deeper. At this point, I believe it's a design defect, as @Nilesh commented.