# How is Reflection Implemented in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, implementation

The Java 7 Language Specifications say pretty early on:

> "this specification does not describe reflection in any detail."

I'm wondering just that: how is Reflection implemented in Java?

I'm not asking how it's used, and I understand there might not be as specific an answer I'm looking for, but any information would be much appreciated.

I've found this on Stackoverflow, the analogous question about C#: [How is reflection implemented in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105575/how-is-reflection-implemented-in-c)

Comment: Pretty much smoke and mirrors.  Lots of `native` methods that dork around in the innards of objects.  A `native` method pretty much can do anything it wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main entry point of any Reflection activity is the `Class` class. From it you can get `Method`, `Field`, `Class`, `Constructor`, and `Annotation` instances.

If you look at the source code, you will notice that to retrieve any of the above, Java has to make a [`native`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101311/what-is-the-native-keyword-in-java-for) call. For example,

```
private native Field[]       getDeclaredFields0(boolean publicOnly);
private native Method[]      getDeclaredMethods0(boolean publicOnly);
private native Constructor<T>[] getDeclaredConstructors0(boolean publicOnly);
private native Class<?>[]   getDeclaredClasses0();
private native byte[] getRawAnnotations(); // get converted to Annotation instances later
```

The implementation is done in native C code (and/or C++). Each JDK might differ, but you can look up the source code if it's available and you have patience. Details on the OpenJDK source code can be found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594046/java-native-method-source-code).