# I tried to view .NET BCL libraries with .NET reflector, but it does not show any symbols

Tags: c#, disassembly, .net-reflector

It show only defination of function inside the class . For egs. I open Read function but it shows only definition like

```
public override int Read([In,Out], byte buffer[], int offset,int count)
```

But .Net reflector shows everything about my .dll file including logic.

Please help i want to hide my logic like microsoft .dll files

Comment: Exact function name could help... Or at least attributes from the function...

Comment: you should write your code in C++

Comment: This is from System.IO namespace.
BinaryReader  Class
Read() function

Comment: I can use Reflector to open System.IO.BinaryReader.Read (and others).  Perhaps you're using Reflector incorrectly?

Comment: I want to know
Code written in C++ can not be able to read by any reflector or tool.
Is it completely safe or not.

Comment: @GlennFerrie It helps, because C++ isn't so easy to read back as code. Though any skilled reverse engineer can give you code that looks very close to it. I recommend putting your code behind a website. So only the result is shown, never the code itself (that generated the page/result).

Comment: Hey @Measuring -- Here's some more info.  the source code for the .NET Base Class Library (BCL) is available online for educational purposes.  your answer is in there.  There are details in my response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105575/how-is-reflection-implemented-in-c/15170733#15170733

Comment: If i use WCF C# dll. Then it is safe. If i place all my important code in WCF dll and Add web service reference .Is it safe or not

Comment: @newuser Yes, if the code is run on a server instead of on the client, it's safe. You'll provide important code though a service using WCF like you said.

Comment: If you don't mind please do accept the answer, if it solved your problem, so that it  would be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can't prevent a managed-DLL from being opened in a decompiler, all what you can do is to [obfuscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) it.
You can use tools like [Dotfuscator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227240.aspx) to obfuscate your code.

[From the official site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227211.aspx)

> Dotfuscator provides all “normal” obfuscation methodologies in
>   addition to many unique ones. No obfuscation technology is 100 percent
>   secure. As with other obfuscators, Dotfuscator makes life more
>   difficult for decompilers and disassemblers; it does not claim 100
>   percent protection.

A few things it accomplishes are :

- Identifier Renaming
- Control Flow Obfuscation
- User String Encryption
- Watermarking
- Tamper Notification and Runtime Intelligence with SO-signal

Comment: I used Dotfuscator but it is not the complete solution for this.
It just changes the function name..

Comment: @newuser There's only one real way to protect your code. And that is to not give it away. Obfuscated, encrypted, whatever or not, there are tools to undo/assist in seeing your code anyway. You'll need to rethink your architecture if you want no one to see it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the source code from the BCL looks like for that method:

```
 public virtual int Read(byte[] buffer, int index, int count) {
        if (buffer==null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_Buffer"));
        if (index < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum"));
        if (count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum"));
        if (buffer.Length - index < count)
            throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_InvalidOffLen"));

        if (m_stream==null) __Error.FileNotOpen();
        return m_stream.Read(buffer, index, count);
    }
```

I think you'll need to dig deeper into the source code to find what you're looking for.

Happy Hunting!

BCL source code: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917

Comment: if i want to make my code look like this .Then what concept i need to implement.

Comment: What is your objective? to inspect the code base?  Download the source from the link I provided.  If you want to get your disassembler to work -- make sure you have the debug symbols loaded.  Try using Telerik JustDecompile.  I think its a better tool than Reflector.